# Why am I getting 'AADSTS90023' error code while connecting to my OneDrive for Business account using Office365-REST-Python-Client library?

Tags: python, sharepoint, onedrive

In order to access files on my OneDrive for Business, I am utilizing the most recent version of the Office365-REST-Python-Client library, which I installed using pip because there is a requirement from the office to upload and download files via python code.
For Authentication, the auth flow I was trying to utilize requires username and password since I have access to them only.
You may see the authentication code below.

```
user_credentials = UserCredential('{username}','{password}') 
ctx = ClientContext('{url}').with_credentials(user_credentials)
```

I have attached my code snippets

`files_handlers.py`

```
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
from sharepoint_config import share_point

class SharePoint:
    def __init__(self, url, username, password)->None:
        self.authenticate(url, username, password)

    def authenticate(self, url, username, password) -> None:
        self.ctx = ClientContext(url).with_user_credentials(username, password)
        self.web = self.ctx.web.get().execute_query()

if __name__ == "__main__":  
    obj = SharePoint(share_point.url,share_point.username,share_point.password)
    print()
```

`sharepoint_config.py` file has:

```
class share_point:
    url = 'https://netorgft14567460-my.sharepoint.com/personal/intel_heal_com'
    username = 'USER NAME'
    password = 'PASSWORD'
```

Now as soon as I run `files_handlers.py` an error is thrown at the line

```
self.web = self.ctx.web.get().execute_query()
```

error:

```
Exception has occurred: ValueError
An error occurred while retrieving token from XML response: AADSTS90023: Invalid STS request.
ValueError: An error occurred while retrieving token from XML response: AADSTS90023: Invalid STS request.
```

I tried debugging and all possible methods but couldn't find a solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are encountering an error when trying to log into Microsoft Teams on your desktop app using your Microsoft Account. The error message "AADSTS90023: Microsoft Account logins are not supported" indicates that your account type is not supported for logging in to Teams through the app.

There could be several reasons why this is happening. One possibility is that there may be an issue with the authentication or authorization process for your Microsoft Account. Another possibility is that there may be a problem with your Teams app installation or configuration.

To troubleshoot this issue, you can try the following steps:

1. Make sure that you are using the latest version of the Teams desktop app. You can check for updates by going to the Teams menu, selecting "Check for updates," and following the prompts.
2. Clear the cache and cookies of the Teams app. To do this, go to the Teams menu, select "Preferences," and then choose "Privacy." From there, you can select "Clear cache and cookies."
3. Check your Microsoft Account to make sure that it is set up correctly and that there are no issues with your account.
4. If none of these steps work, you can try uninstalling and reinstalling the Teams desktop app

Comment: Thank you for kindly extending your assistance. Your support has been invaluable. However, I would like to clarify that my query pertains to accessing my OneDrive for business account, and not to connecting to Teams as indicated in the title of my inquiry. I would be most grateful if you could guide me in this regard.accessing my OneDrive for business account. Could you kindly assist me with this matter?